# Orchard Deployment problems 404 error

Tags: c#, content-management-system, orchardcms

I love orchard, I am a .net deveoper looking to use this as a cms, followed the orchard cms book great everything is really good... now the problem I thought lets see if i can deploy this on my vps... presented big problems with lots of errors.

So i went back to basics downloaded a fresh copy of orchard...and ran the first time set up and tried to deploy that... I am using visual studio 2012 i right clicked published chose to publish to file system then ftp across to server... copied app data folder in binary mode changed the settings.txt to point to my prod database.

> Tried to open the website and just get a 404 error.. when I look in
>   the app logs this is what i see..  2013-05-02 11:40:52,439 [15]
>   Orchard.FileSystems.AppData.AppDataFolder - Could not delete recipe
>   execution folder
>   C:\Websites\OrchardTestDeploy\src\Orchard.Web\App_Data\RecipeQueue\25fc7ed3855649e68c0435a7dcf412b3
>   under "App_Data" folder  2013-05-02 11:44:45,702 [6]
>   Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost - A tenant could not be
>   started: Default  Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of
>   the constructors found with
>   'Orchard.Environment.AutofacUtil.DynamicProxy2.ConstructorFinderWrapper'
>   on type 'Orchard.Settings.CurrentSiteWorkContext' can be invoked with
>   the available services and parameters:  Cannot resolve parameter
>   'Orchard.Settings.ISiteService siteService' of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(Orchard.Settings.ISiteService)'.  at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable1 parameters)  at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable1
>   parameters)  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.b__0() 
>   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id,
>   Func1 creator)  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
>
> at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope
>   currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration,
>   IEnumerable1 parameters)  at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)

Which is worse than my daisy website with new modules and lots of errors... am i doing something wrong... there must be a simple approach other than the installation guide on this site that says zip up the whole project and deploy it.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have all the correct permissions on your server

Answer (score 2):

> You might have to set read/write permissions for the account that is
>   configured as the identity for the IIS application pool on the
>   following folders:
>
> - Modules
> - Themes
> - App_Data
> - Media

Taken from [Orchard documentation - Manually installing Orchard](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Manually-installing-Orchard-zip-file).